# Store large 3D grid with fine spacing

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am creating a large 3D grid of size 1000,1000,1000 but it is memory hungry. I am saving values using 3 loops for a grid vector

```
for (i=0; i<1000;i++)
for (j=0; j<1000;j++)
for (k=0; k<1000;k++)
MyGrid[i][j][k] = Random_Number
```

Where Random_Number is value of grid at i,j,k. MyGrid stores value of grid for index i,j, k. for example, if we have a unit cube (000,100,010,001,110,011,101,111) then MyGrid store the value of cube at 000, etc. For example at 000 it is 0.4, 100 it is 9.0 etc.  But this grid is large so there are many cubes. I have to use grid value for indexing purpose. Is there any efficient way to store grid value. Other option I may have to store data in 2D vector which is simple. But how to find index value? e.g

```
Mygrid[i][j] = i, j, k, p1, p2, p3, p5
```

if i am visiting grid point i,j,k then how to read p1, p2, p3 etc from  from Mygrid?

I try boost but even with boost for small spacing there is a problem

```
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type MyGrid(boost::extents[1000][1000][1000]);
```

and program crashes..  I want to save grid point information and retrieve it later for moving a object inside the grid. Object position will be retrieved using simple interpolation based on grid point value. So idea is if i know value of my moving object at i,j,k position in the grid then I can easily determined value of my moving object at any random point inside the grid using  simple interpolation.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you try to make your question more clear and provide some context for what MyGrid is?

Comment: updated. MyGrid is value at corner of a cube. But if spacing is very small then i am running memory problem. For example is my grid size is 1000,1000,1000 and spacing is 0.2, then I am in trouble, if it is 1 then it is working fine. Next time if i want to read value at 4,6,11 then I can look at MyGrid[4][6][11] and print its value.. It is some sort of look up table

Comment: a sparse array?

Comment: so your question is "Is there any efficient way to store grid value" ? so u need to tell what requirement on efficiency you have, space? speed?

Comment: For large grid both space and speed. So I was thinking if i can store i,j,k and value of grid in 2D arrary. This will save memory but getting value of grid at  4,6,11, i have to scan whole 2D array which take lots of time. So is there any alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: It won't save you memory wether you store your cube position values as `i,j,k` or `i,j` or as a 1D array. And sparse array depends if most of your values are 0 or some constant number.

Comment: So, how can I read cube corner value using 2D vector for a given i, j, k?

Comment: I don't understand.  A cube has less than 1000 vertices.  You could define a cube with less than 10 *points*, where a *point* is a structure with 3 ordinates.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I still have no idea what you are asking. You have `1000^3` numbers you are storing. However you choose to store them is going to take up the same amount of memory, whether it is 1D, 2D, or 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply trying to place 3d objects in a 3d space?  Why don't you just store the few objects you have, with their size and location?  That would save a lot of memory.

ex:

```
struct ParallepipedRect
{
  int x, y, z;       // upper-left-closest corner
  int cx, cy, cz;    // dimensions
};
```

Going through a list of those for hit/miss test would be really fast.

If you need better resolution - finer spacing? - , use `float`, or `double` instead of `int`

If your master grid has a lot of zero values, another solution could be to have each object hold its own 'mini' grid.

```
struct Object
{
   int x_, y_, z_;              // << object center.
   double grid_[21][21][21];    // << could be a vector<vector<vector<double>>>;

   double InfluenceAt(int x, int y, int z)
   {
       double result = 0;
       int lx = x - x_;         // compute local coordinates
       int ly = y - y_;
       int lz = z - z_;

       if (   (lx < 0 || 21 <= lx)
           || (ly < 0 || 21 <= ly)
           || (lz < 0 || 21 <= lz) )
       {
          return 0;
       }
       return grid_[lx][ly][lz];  
   }
};
```

You'd have to loop through your objects and add/do whatever computation your lookup table does for object interference.  But that would free up 3+GB of memory.

Or you could find an open source package that handles sparse matrices.  There are plenty of them out there.

Comment: I want to save and grid point value for moving a object inside the grid. So grid point value will be used for interpolation purpose and grid value can be read as a look up table. Thats why i need a big grid.

Comment: If most of your grid elements are `zero`, you are better off without such a large look-up table.

Answer (score 1):

After I read the description and your comments, it sounds like you are just trying to store, retrieve, or gain spacial information about objects. Have you considered a more efficient data structure like an [R*-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*_tree)? It sounds like you're familiar with Boost, and there already exists an [implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html) you might be able to use.

Comment: I am not familiar with R-tree but will read about it. You are right i want to store and retrieve grid point information for other purpose.